# How to get the outbuild build directory in VSTS after a YARN BUILD

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-devops, yarnpkg

I created a build definition using yarn custom extensions.

[image]

The build works fine:

[image]

But, apparently the yarn build task does not generate any output

[image]

What am I missing here to be able to generate a build output that I can deploy to azure?

Update 1:
I was able to configure the copy, but its copying the entire folder even with node_modules to the drop.  There should be a build folder only

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task "Publish Artifact" publishes the build artifacts that exist on the agent in folder "a".

If you don't copy the output to folder "a", the publish task will not publish anything and you will get the message:

> Directory '...\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build...

Before the Publish Artifact task, you need to add the [Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=vsts) task, in this task you should copy the Yarn output to the folder "a" in the agent, after it the publish will success.

Comment: and what is the source folder? https://screencast.com/t/PaTa9spv1AL, its not in the git repo, but I suppose a special vsts variable holds the yarn output folder?\

Comment: @LuisValencia Keep the default variables on the task Copy Files, and in the contents replace the `**` in the necessary folder.